# Celery not running as daemon

Tags: python, celery

I launch Celery workers through the following python script

```
subprocess.Popen("celery -A test_celery worker -Q {} --loglevel=info -n {} -Ofair ".format(str(ContactID)+'_rec',worker1),shell=True,stdin=None, stdout=open(os.devnull, 'wb'), stderr=open(os.devnull, 'wb'))
```

When I run this Python script as sudo user or as service, the Celery does not work, but executing it as normal Ubuntu user works fine.

Answer (score 1):

It can be done by specifying the user in the Service section of the .service file